# How can i simplify checking if a value exist in Json doc

Tags: node.js

Here is my scenario, i am parsing via javascript a webpage and then post the result to an restApi to store the json in a db. The code works fine as long as all fields i defined in my script are send. Problem is over time they website might change names for fields and that would cause my code to crash.
Originally i used code like this

```
const mySchool = new mls.School();
    mySchool.highSchoolDistrict = data["HIGH SCHOOL DISTRICT"].trim();
    mySchool.elementary = data.ELEMENTARY.trim();
    mySchool.elementaryOther = data["ELEMENTARY OTHER"].trim();
    mySchool.middleJrHigh = data["MIDDLE/JR HIGH"].trim();
    mySchool.middleJrHighOther = data["MIDDLE/JR HIGH OTHER"].trim();
    mySchool.highSchool = data["HIGH SCHOOL"].trim();
    mySchool.highSchoolOther = data["HIGH SCHOOL OTHER"].trim();
    newListing.school = mySchool;
```

but when the element does not exist it complains about that it can not use trim of undefined. So to fix this i came up with this

```
if (data["PATIO/PORCH"]) {
        newExterior.patioPorch = data["PATIO/PORCH"].trim();
    }
```

this works but i am wondering if there is a more global approach then to go and check each field if it is defined ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could leverage a sort of helper function to check first if the item is `undefined`, and if not, return a `trim()`-ed version of the string.

```js
var data = Array();
data["HIGH SCHOOL DISTRICT"] = " 123 ";

function trimString(inputStr) {
  return (inputStr != undefined && typeof inputStr == "string") ? inputStr.trim() : undefined;
}

console.log(trimString(data["HIGH SCHOOL DISTRICT"]));
console.log(trimString(data["ELEMENTARY OTHER"]));
```